# Could not find a package configuration file provided by "tf2" with any of the following names

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have downloaded the tf2 package recently and I am hoping to process the packages for my turtlebot 3 burger.

The error messages are:

```
Could not find the required component 'tf2'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "tf2" with any of
  the following names:

    tf2Config.cmake
    tf2-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "tf2" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "tf2_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "tf2" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/pi/catkin_ws/build_isolated/tf2_py/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/pi/catkin_ws/build_isolated/tf2_py/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
<== Failed to process package 'tf2_py': 
  Command '['/home/pi/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/test_rosservice/env.sh', 'cmake', '/home/pi/catkin_ws/src/geometry2/tf2_py', '-DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/pi/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/tf2_py', '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/pi/catkin_ws/install_isolated', '-G', 'Unix Makefiles']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Please advise.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345098/could-not-find-a-package-configuration-file-provided-by-%22tf2%22-with-any-of---the-following-names/) by [AHJL001](https://answers.ros.org/users/51756/ahjl001/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2020-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
sudo apt install ros-<distro>-tf2*
```

In general, you should get familiar with [rosdep](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdep) & errors like this. That's just the canonical error for "yo, you're missing the package mate".

> error indicates that you either need
> to install the package with the same
> name or change your environment so
> that it can be found.

This error is pretty straight forward but I agree all the text around it can be overwhelming if you're new to C++

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHJL001](https://answers.ros.org/users/51756/ahjl001/) on 2020-02-26**:
Thank you for the prompt reply. However, after typing that command, trying `ros-kinetic-tf2*` , `ros-kinetic-tf2` and also `ros-indigo-tf2*` , `ros-indigo-tf2` . The result are similar to:

```
E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-tf2*
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'ros-kinetic-tf2*'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'ros-kinetic-tf2*'
```

Side note: I have the tf2 package in my src folder of the workspace.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-26**:
Seeing as the OP has mentioned Raspbian, there is a good chance he's build ROS from source.

In that case you cannot use `apt` to install additional packages.

**Comment by [AHJL001](https://answers.ros.org/users/51756/ahjl001/) on 2020-02-26**:
@gvdhoorn Yes, I am processing these packages from a Raspberry Pi 3B+ on my turtlebot. I have the tf2 package file in the src folder. The command I am using to process the packages is `catkin_make_isolated`. I am not sure if it will affect the processing, forgive me.

**Comment by [phil123456](https://answers.ros.org/users/51234/phil123456/) on 2020-03-05**:
nice, now how do we install packages ??